# vkMapMemory validation error on vkQueuePresentKHR, but never called the function directly

Tags: vulkan

When calling vkQueuePresentKHR i get the following validation error:

```
Validation Error: [ VUID-vkMapMemory-size-00680 ] Object 0: handle = 0x8483000000000025, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE_MEMORY; | MessageID = 0xff4787ab | VkMapMemory: Attempting to map memory range of size zero The Vulkan spec states: If size is not equal to VK_WHOLE_SIZE, size must be greater than 0 (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.148.0/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkMapMemory-size-00680)
```

I never called vkMapMemory() directly.

Here is an excerpt of my code:  https://gist.github.com/alexandru-cazacu/7847161564daa5f93d1bada39280faa8

Comment: Check which implicit layers are runing, and blacklist them or update them.

Comment: Closing RivaTuner Statistics Server fixed the problem. I had 3 other validation errors caused by it.

Answer (score 0):

Closing RivaTuner Statistics Server fixed the issue.

I had 3 other validation errors caused by it.

As stated in https://vulkan-tutorial.com/FAQ

> **I get an access violation error in the core validation layer**: Make sure that MSI Afterburner / RivaTuner Statistics Server is not
> running, because it has some compatibility problems with Vulkan.